# How to check in an array if a value exists

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I am building an javascript app with Backbone/Marionette (and Coffeescript) and I want to check if a value is contained within a textfield.

If I do this it does not work:

```
questions = $("input[name='questions']").val().split(',')
      if questions.indexOf(1) == -1
        @ui.check.removeClass("green")
      else
        @ui.check.addClass("green")
```

If I do this it works (hard code the array):

```
questions = [1]
      if questions.indexOf(1) == -1
        @ui.check.removeClass("green")
      else
        @ui.check.addClass("green")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried printing the value of questions and seeing if it's what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

From the fine [`String.prototype.split` manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

> **Return value**
>
> An array of strings split at each point where the separator occurs in the given string.

and the fine [`Array.prototype.indexOf` manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

> **Description**
>
> `indexOf()` compares `searchElement` to elements of the Array using strict equality (the same method used by the `===` or triple-equals operator).

So when you say this:

```
questions = $("input[name='questions']").val().split(',')
if questions.indexOf(1) == -1
  #...
```

you're searching an array of strings (`questions`) for a number using strict equality. In JavaScript, `1 === '1'` will never be true (unlike `1 == '1'`) so your search will fail to find anything. Your hard-coded example works because `question` is an array of numbers (not strings) there.

Either search for a string:

```
if questions.indexOf('1') == -1
```

or convert your strings to numbers before searching:

```
questions = $("input[name='questions']").val().split(',').map (s) -> +s
if questions.indexOf(1) == -1
```

Which approach you'd use depends on where the `1` comes from and what else you plan to do with `questions`.